# Histogram with Bins

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have list of numbers and I want to plot histogram for that plot but I need to divide that list into bins like total values between 0-100 in first bar, values between 100-200 in second bar and so on...

List of number looks like:

```
array([144., 266., 274., 589., 109., 363.,  49.,  99., 574.,   8.,   2., 13.,  15.])
```

I did something like

```
plt.hist(n_points_list, bins = 100)
```

[image]

but instead of this I need the plot values in list between 0-100 in one group, 100-200 in another group and so on...

Comment: Use `bins = range(0,max(n_points_list)+100, 100)` to have bins of width 100.

Comment: `bins=range(0,int(max(a)+100), 100)`

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your help.